# How Can I Write this to File Using PHP?

Tags: php, csv, fopen

I have been working with a script to change my CSV file to Tab Delimited.  It seems to work great, but it is read-only.  How do I go about actually writing the changes to the file?  Here is the script:

```
<?php
$myfile = "/path/to/my.csv";
$csv_fp = fopen ($myfile, "r");
$rows = 0;
      while ($data = fGetCsv ($csv_fp, 10000, ",")) 
{
$num = count($data);
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
   echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
      }

$rows++;
}fclose ($csv_fp);  
?>
```

Comment: How about `file_put_contents('/path/to/my.csv', $data)`?

Comment: Do I just put     file_put_contents('/path/to/my.csv', $data)     before the    fclose ($csv_fp);    ?

Comment: Also, how do you format comments as code here at Stack Overflow?

Comment: I gave you a solution on how to convert a comma delimited CSV to a tab delimited one. You can format code in comments by using backticks `\`code here\``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can change a comma delimited CSV to a tab delimited. However, I don't see the benefits of doing this. I think comma delimited CSVs are much less prone to errors.

```
<?php
$myfile = "/path/to/my.csv";
$csv_fread = fopen($myfile, 'r');

$rows = array();
while ($columns = fgetcsv($csv_fread, 10000, ",")) {
    $rows[] = $columns;
}
fclose($csv_fread);


$csv_fwrite = fopen($myfile, 'w');
foreach($rows as $row){
    fputcsv($csv_fwrite, $row, "\t");
}
fclose($csv_fwrite);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample but it gives the following error `fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` it seems to come from the line `foreach($rows as $row){
    fputcsv($csv_fwrite, $row, "\t");
}` Do you know what that means?

Comment: @Presto: Did you change the file path on `$myfile`? It seems like the `$csv_fwrite` is not opening the file for write. If you have changed the file path, then the issue might be the file permissions, you might not have write permission on the file.

Comment: That was it!  I changed the permissions of the file and it was able to go through.  Now I just have to figure out how to use `file_put_contents` and save it as a new `.txt` file. Thanks again for all the help :)

Comment: @Presto: I have already provided the functionality, which will manipulate the CSV. From there one you just do a simple `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the mode in your call to fopen from `r` to one that opens the file in write mode.  Which one you choose depends on what you want to do (append, overwrite).  I am guessing that you want to overwrite, in which case you can choose `w` or `w+`.

Check out the manual for [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it blew up with errors.  I guess I was looking for more of a code sample from this script as a fix for this issue if possible.